# How can i do Promise all in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used Promise.all and I'm not getting a single promise at the end but promise should accept a bunch of individual promises and gives you back a single promise right?

I have a for loop which will calls a method that does stuff asynchronously. This loop can call the method many times. After this loop, I have another loop that needs to be executed only when all the stuff is done.

```
function doSomethingAsync(i) {
// do your stuf 
    setValue(i, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })
}
```

some one could help me here.i'm not sure my implementation is correct or not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `doSomethingAsync` does not return any Promises. Instead, it uses callbacks. You can wrap it like this.

```js
function doSomethingAsync(i) {
// do your stuf 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setValue(i, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            resolve(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            resolve(result);
        }
    })
    })
}
```